# how can I target a <input type="image" ....> using capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, capybara, capybara-webkit

This is part of my view  ...

```
  <input type="image" id="clickAction" src="<%= @bookSurveyImage %>" alt="Take Survey"%>"/>
<% end %>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to be able to target that input, to be redirect to another url. How can I do this ? Please help

Below are some of the things that I have tried.

```
describe "landings", :type => :feature do
it "index: get all params" do
visit '/sample_page?'

expect(page).to have_no_content 'Sample text'
expect(page).to have_no_content 'Example'
expect(page).to have_no_content("Some Content")

expect(page).to have_css("img", :maximum => 1)

# expect(page).to have_css("input", :id => "sampleID")
# get :survey_link
# expect(response).to render_template(:survey_link) #
# find("#clickAction").click
# input[@type='image']
# click_input

# 

# visit 'https://url........'
```

end
end

Comment: Provide some more description. What exactly you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to click that with

```
click_button("Take Survey")
```

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Node/Actions#click_button-instance_method

Comment: Thank you, but this does not work, because my input is an image. The user is supposed to click the image and then be redirected. this is the error I get `Failure/Error: click_button("Take Survey")
     
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find visible button "Take Survey"
`

Comment: @user3643216 Then you're not actually on the page you think you are (or the page doesn't have the contents you think it does) -- as  mentioned in the docs I linked to  - click_button will find inputs of type "image" and a matching `alt` attribute.  This all assumes you're not doing something like blocking images from loading - so the input ends up being 0px x 0px and unfindable/unclickable

Answer (score 0):

You can use Capybara's `find` method. You can locate the element based on its id attribute, in this case, `clickAction`. Here's an example of how you can do it:

Assuming you have set up your Capybara session (e.g., using Selenium or another driver)

Find the input element by its id:

```
image_input = find('input#clickAction')
```

Perform actions on the element, for example, clicking it:

```
image_input.click
```

Make sure you've properly set up Capybara with your chosen driver for this to work.